# AVAudioSession crashing in new Thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiscrollview, avaudiosession

I have a Method wich create an UIScrollView and your subviews programmatically. One of your views is a MoviewPlayer...While the scrollview is being created, I need to allow the user to exit the screen (before the loading ends). Then, I've called this method in another NSThread.

**But I'm getting the following error:**

> [__NSCFData _pickableRoutesDidChangeNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

I think it's not possible to do it in another Thread. Then, How could I allow the user to exit the view before the loading ends?

Theres my code:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(criarScrollMidias:) toTarget:self withObject:self.eventoAtual];
}

-(void) criarScrollMidias:(Evento *)evento {
     NSLog(@"criar scroll midias");

     NSMutableArray *listaImagens = evento.atracao.images;
     NSMutableArray *listaVideos = evento.atracao.videos;

     if([listaVideos count] > 0) {
       self.listaVideoPlayers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     }

     [self.scrollImVd setPagingEnabled:YES];

      if(![self.eventoAtual.atracao.imageLarge isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    {

    UIImageView *imgViewAtracao = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:self.eventoAtual.atracao.imageLarge];
    [imgViewAtracao setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    [imgViewAtracao setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollImVd.frame.size.width, self.scrollImVd.frame.size.height)];
    [self.scrollImVd addSubview:imgViewAtracao];
    }

  for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < [listaImagens count]; iCnt++) {
      NSString *imgURL = [listaImagens objectAtIndex:iCnt];
      UIImage *imagemAtracao = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]]];
      UIImageView *imgViewAtracao = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:imagemAtracao];

      [imgViewAtracao setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

      if(![self.eventoAtual.atracao.imageLarge isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        [imgViewAtracao setFrame:CGRectMake(0+self.scrollImVd.frame.size.width*(iCnt+1), 0, self.scrollImVd.frame.size.width, self.scrollImVd.frame.size.height)];
    else
        [imgViewAtracao setFrame:CGRectMake(0+self.scrollImVd.frame.size.width*iCnt, 0, self.scrollImVd.frame.size.width, self.scrollImVd.frame.size.height)];

    [self.scrollImVd addSubview:imgViewAtracao];
}

for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt < [listaVideos count]; iCnt++) {
    NSString *videoURLStr = [listaVideos objectAtIndex:iCnt];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoURLStr];
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
    moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    [moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];
    [moviePlayer.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[self gerarPreviewVideo:videoURL]]];

    CGFloat posicaoInicial = 0.0;
    if(![self.eventoAtual.atracao.imageLarge isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
        posicaoInicial = self.scrollImVd.frame.size.width * ([listaImagens count] + 1);
    else
        posicaoInicial = self.scrollImVd.frame.size.width * [listaImagens count];

    [moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(posicaoInicial+self.scrollImVd.frame.size.width*iCnt, 0, self.scrollImVd.frame.size.width, self.scrollImVd.frame.size.height)];

    UIButton *playButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(moviePlayer.view.frame.origin.x+(self.scrollImVd.frame.size.width/2)-34, moviePlayer.view.frame.origin.y+(self.scrollImVd.frame.size.height/2)-33, 67, 66)];
    [playButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    playButton.tag = iCnt;
    [playButton addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.scrollImVd addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [self.scrollImVd addSubview:playButton];
    [self.listaVideoPlayers addObject:moviePlayer];
}

if(![self.eventoAtual.atracao.imageLarge isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    [self.scrollImVd setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollImVd.frame.size.width * ([listaImagens count] + [listaVideos count] + 1), self.scrollImVd.frame.size.height)];
else
     [self.scrollImVd setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.scrollImVd.frame.size.width * ([listaImagens count] + [listaVideos count]), self.scrollImVd.frame.size.height)];
[self.viewLoading setHidden:YES];

   }
```

I've debugged and discovered that the problem is when I try to generate the preview in another Thread:

```
 -(UIImage *) gerarPreviewVideo:(NSURL *)videoURL {
    AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:videoURL options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generateImg = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    NSError *error = NULL;
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 65);
    CGImageRef refImg = [generateImg copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&error];
    UIImage *thumbnail= [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:refImg];
    return thumbnail;
}
```

How could I resolve it?

Comment: is it your method pickableRoutesDidChangeNotification if yes then it is calling as NSData method.your error showing that method is not a method of NSData.

Comment: @johnykumar pickableRoutesDidChangeNotification is a native method from MPMoviePlayerController

Comment: please verify again wether it is MPMoviePlayerController method or not.

Comment: @johnykumar thanks. Please see my edit